Understanding Netdata Warnings/Report
We're getting constant Swap memory Utilization warnings between 70% to even 100%, we have about 7 - 8 applications on this VPS which is deployed on Linode through Runcloud. This isn't happening on any of our other servers and we have been unable to identify the specific app which is causing this issue. Is there any way to figure out using the netdata which application, database or process is causing this? 1
